# iframe behaves like an image element in terms of aspect ratio and responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

There are [plenty solutions](https://davidwalsh.name/responsive-iframes) out there where the width is responsive and the iframe retains aspect ratio but i cannot find a solution that also incorporates iframe height aswell.

In regards to the above solutions out there, if the iframe solution has a parent div whose height can change, the solutions just cuts off the bottom of the iframe if the height is to small instead of being responsive.

I need a solution that applies to the the case when you have a changing height and width of a parent element that the iframe is in, for use across different devices and view port sizes.

The solution should allow the iframe to behave like a responsive image element, that retains aspect ratio when the size changes on both width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your iframe responsive by utilising `position: absolute;` in the container, however you will need to ensure there is a set height on the container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this means the height is not responsive still.

Answer (score 0):

I used the media query aspect ratio to get the desired result